# How make docker to work under Cisco AnyConnect VPN connection?

Tags: macos, vpn, docker, osx-el-capitan, cisco-vpn-client

When I'm initializing VPN connection via Cisco AnyConnect client, I'm loosing connection to docker daemon. My guess (backed by some googling) is that this has something to do with with routing rewritten by AnyConnect.

The question is - how this can be circumvented?
I've tried to launch and re-launch docker daemon after VPN connection established but this naïve attempt just predictably failed.

Then I've googled a bunch of proposed quite kludgy solutions, for instance, [this guy suggests](https://www.iancollington.com/docker-and-cisco-anyconnect-vpn/) to forward ports and then just always use `docker --tlsverify=false` - I don't want to do this.

Other thing I've tried to do is to use solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992729/cannot-get-docker-machine-to-work-with-virtualbox-when-using-cisco-vpn-anyconnec):

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "25.0.1.100/24" default
```

This does not work for me as well.

So I'm looking for canonical solution which can be beneficial for other docker users as well.

My docker version is `1.11.2`, OS is `OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this problem on Ubuntu 18.04, use the Network manager instead of Cisco AnyConnect:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc-gnome
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

[image]

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/789478/868453

Answer (score 0):

I only had problems with AnyConnect on OSX plus they stop development so instead I switched to openconnect, you can install it from homebrew

`brew install openconnect`

No more rewritten routes

Comment: It is not correct that AnyConnect development on OSX platform is stopped. Please look at [release notes](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/products-release-notes-list.html) for the enhancements and bugs resolved for each release.

Comment: You are right @Mahesh I should have mentioned that I wasn't able to migrate to version 4 of the AnyConnect client and that version 3.1 is eol http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/eos-eol-notice-c51-734084.html